# reading and sorting files from a directory with for loop in python

Tags: python, file, sorting, concatenation

**Hi Guys,
I have 13 .npy file in a directory. Some of them start with the same name.
Example:**

> B59_180322_153253.npy
>
> B59_180322_173253.npy
>
> B60_180324_153253.npy
>
> B60_180324_173253.npy
>
> B61_180324_173253.npy
>
> B62_180324_173253.npy
>   ....
>   ....

I need to read them and concatenate the ones which starts with the same name (B59) in a for loop then assign to dictionary data. But I could not find an automated way for this.
Do you have any suggestion?
>

> data = {'B59':[], 
>               'B62':[],
>
> ```
>         'B65':[],
>
>         'B67':[],
>
>         'B68':[],
>
>         'B79':[],
>
>         'B80':[]}
> ```

The code works nicely when there are no multiple files which starts with the same name. ANY will be appreciated, thanks in advance.
Best

> for file in glob.glob("*.npy"):
>
> ```
>    experiment_id=file.split('_')[0]
>
>    print(experiment_id)
>
>    var = np.load(file)
>
>   data[experiment_id]=var
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.

## Iterate over your txt files

With the below code I am able to create dictionary with keys that have file names. So I dont have write it myself.
But still the dictionary gets only the first npy file when there are 2 starting with the same name.

And this one did not work, so I removed it and 
data[experiment_id].append(var)

```
direc = os.getcwd() # Get current working directory
text = '.npy' # Select your file delimiter

file_dict = {} # Create an empty dict

# Select only files with the ext extension
txt_files = [i for i in os.listdir(direc) if os.path.splitext(i)[1] == ext]

for f in txt_files:
   with open(os.path.join(direc,f)) as file_object:
   experiment_id=f.split('_')[0]
   print(experiment_id)
   file_dict[experiment_id]=np.load(f)
```

What do you think can be added on here?